# django run server is not working from crontab script

Tags: django, linux, bash, cron, netstat

I m writing my cronjob as below:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /root/gitsync.sh
```

and content of gitsync.sh is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /root/devices-web

git checkout main

git pull

echo "log1" >> /root/log.txt

pip install -r requirements.txt

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Script is getting called every 5 minutes, but services are not running.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem with the script or the runserver? What do you mean by 'services not running'?